# (Swift) upload Image to backend not working and Worked in (Postman) & (Admin Page)

Tags: swift, urlsession

Trying to Upload Image From Swift APP to backend

tested on Admin Page working fine I can upload image.

tested on Postman and its working fine I can upload image.

when I try to upload from swift I got invalid_image

I am Taking UIImage and converted using pngData and send it in URLSession:
param["src"] contains UIImage

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: ServerURL)!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
    let boundary = "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"
    request.addValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    request.httpMethod = "PUT"
var body = ""
for param in parameters {
        if param["disabled"] == nil {
            let paramName = param["key"]!
            body += "--\(boundary)\r\n"
            body += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(paramName)\""
            if param["contentType"] != nil {
                body += "\r\nContent-Type: \(param["contentType"] as! String)"
            }
            let paramType = param["type"] as! String
            if paramType == "text" {
                let paramValue = param["value"] as! String
                body += "\r\n\r\n\(paramValue)\r\n"
            } else {
            let paramSrc = param["src"] as! UIImage
            let fileData = (String(data: fileData, encoding: .utf8) ?? "Converting to UTF8 Fail") as String
            body += "; filename=\"myImg.png\"\r\n"
            body += "Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n\(fileData)\r\n"
```

Checked paramSrc and its content the image but fileData got nil

I have try :

```
let fileData = paramSrc.pngData()! as NSData
```

and fileData was contain the data not nil but still getting

```
ErrorDetail(string='Upload a valid image. The file you uploaded was either not an image or a corrupted image.', code='invalid_image')
```

SOLVE it ( send it as Data ) :

thanks for @pastre for helping find where is the problem happen

Comment: Can you provide the code that's running on your backend? Or an URL so that we can better debug alternatives?

Comment: @Pastre Thanks for replay Code has been added

Comment: Don't you need to decode from base64 into a file in order to save your image as an ImageField?

Comment: @Pastre I want to encode it UTF8 but always return nil

Comment: So paramSrc.pngData()?.base64EncodedString() is returning nil? @Bosoud

Comment: @Pastre sorry I have removed that line and replace it with utf8 because base64 work fine in swift but my server didn't accept it

Comment: @Pastre I just solve it Send the file as data without convert it and its work !!! is it safe to send the file as data ?

Comment: I don't think it is, you might need to decode from base64 on your backend

Comment: Please don't edit the solution into the question, use the answers section for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if any one got on same problem this is how I solve it

I just change the body from string to data

```
var body = Data()
```

and then

```
 if let fileData = paramSrc.pngData() {
                        body.append("; filename=\"blah.png\"\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
                        body.append("Content-Type: \"content-type header\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
                        body.append(fileData)
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem while uploading image to REST Framework API and fixed it by :

views.py

```
from rest_framework.parsers import FormParser, MultiPartParser


class ClassName(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser, )

    def put(self, request, format=None):
        instance = request.user
        serializer = ClassNameSerializer(instance, data=request.data)
        
        if not serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            return Response({
                "error": serializer.errors
            })
        serializer.save()

        return Response({
            "detail": "Model object updated",
        })
```

serializers.py

```
class ClassNameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ClassName
        fields = ['profile_image', 'full_name', 'address', 'email', 'address']

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):

        if 'profile_image' in validated_data.keys():
            instance.profile_image = validated_data['profile_image']
        if 'full_name' in validated_data.keys():
            instance.full_name = validated_data['full_name']
        if 'email' in validated_data.keys():
            instance.email = validated_data['email'].lower()
        if 'address' in validated_data.keys():
            instance.address = validated_data['address']


        instance.save()
        return instance
```

so as you can see I had not done much file handling in serializers, so in your case add these and try again:

views.py

```
from rest_framework.parsers import FormParser, MultiPartParser

class PUser(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser, )
    def patch(self, request, format=None):
```

Please try and see if it works for you.